# Mysql update query with select with join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to run mysql update query with select in it , but I'm getting an error. Query is this:

```
UPDATE keywords_stats_google_temp SET (Impressions_chg, Clicks_chg, AveragePosition_chg, Ctr_chg, AverageCpc_chg, CurrentMaxCpc_chg, FreeJoins_chg, PaidJoins_chg) = (SELECT 
                SUM(Impressions) AS Impressions,
                SUM(Clicks) AS Clicks,
                SUM(Impressions*AveragePosition)/SUM(Impressions) AS AveragePosition,
                (SUM(Clicks)*revenue_price)/SUM(Impressions) AS Ctr,
                SUM(Spend)/SUM(Clicks) AS AverageCpc,
                CurrentMaxCpc,
                SUM(free_joins) AS FreeJoins,
                SUM(paid_joins) AS PaidJoins
                FROM (SELECT KeywordId FROM keywords_stats_google_temp) a JOIN keywords_stats_google_naughtymeetings b ON b.KeywordId = a.KeywordId WHERE b.TimePeriod >= '2012-04-01 00:00:00'
                AND b.TimePeriod <= '2012-04-23 00:00:00' GROUP BY a.KeywordId, MatchType)
```

But I'm getting only "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Impressions_chg, Clicks_chg, AveragePosition_chg, Ctr_chg, AverageCpc_chg, Curr' at line 1"

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't have `SET (a,b) = (value_a, value_b)` in MySQL.

Comment: Actually I checked an article and there is such a way: http://karlssonondatabases.blogspot.com/2009/01/multicolumn-update-with-subquery-mysql.html

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But not with this syntax. You'll have to rewrite the statement using MySQL syntax for `UPDATE`.

Comment: Can you give me some more info about that? Thx

Comment: What is confusing is the `MatchType` in the `GROUP BY`. Is there a relevant field in the table to be updated?

Comment: Yes, basically grouping by is by two columns - KeywordId and MatchType. But it's never updated, we use it only to update all keywords from the exact matchtype.

Comment: Is there a `keywords_stats_google_temp.MatchType` column? If there is, it should be used in the `ON` clause too, for joining.

Comment: Yes, there is . http://screencast.com/t/8X8npa3GfzD. I just fixed the query now, but I get #1054 - Unknown column 'a.MatchType' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 9):

You can't have `SET (a,b) = (value_a, value_b)` in MySQL.

Rewrite the query. Something like this:

```
UPDATE 
    keywords_stats_google_temp AS u
  JOIN
    ( SELECT 
          SUM(Impressions) AS Impressions,
          SUM(Clicks) AS Clicks,
          SUM(Impressions*AveragePosition)/SUM(Impressions) AS AveragePosition,
          (SUM(Clicks)*revenue_price) / SUM(Impressions) AS Ctr,
          SUM(Spend)/SUM(Clicks) AS AverageCpc,
          CurrentMaxCpc,
          SUM(free_joins) AS FreeJoins,
          SUM(paid_joins) AS PaidJoins
      FROM keywords_stats_google_naughtymeetings AS b  
      WHERE b.TimePeriod >= '2012-04-01 00:00:00'
        AND b.TimePeriod <= '2012-04-23 00:00:00' 
      GROUP BY KeywordId, 
               MatchType
    ) AS tmp
        ON  tmp.KeywordId = u.KeywordId 
        AND tmp.MatchType = u.MatchType
SET 
  u.Impressions_chg     = tmp.Impressions, 
  u.Clicks_chg          = tmp.Clicks, 
  u.AveragePosition_chg = tmp.AveragePosition, 
  u.Ctr_chg             = tmp.Ctr,
  u.AverageCpc_chg      = tmp.AverageCpc, 
  u.CurrentMaxCpc_chg   = tmp.CurrentMaxCpc, 
  u.FreeJoins_chg       = tmp.FreeJoins, 
  u.PaidJoins_chg       = tmp.PaidJoins ;
```

Comment: I run this query and it looks like it's working, but it's very very slow. Probably there should be away to optimize this ...

Comment: Compound index on `(KeywordId, MatchType)` would help on table `u`. Not sure about the other.

Comment: First test that the subquery (with the `GROUP BY`) calculates what it should calculate. After you are sure, then try to optimize the UPDATE.

Comment: @pocko If this solution worked for you, please consider marking it as the Accepted Answer.